# Showing decimal point in gauge meter in d3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am creating project using reactjs. I am integrating gauge meter in my current project. I have implemented successfully gauge meter in my project,but only one problem is i want to display decimal value.here is am using:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-d3-speedometer

This is my code:

```
ReactSpeedometer forceRender = {
                        false
                    }
                    value = {
                        this.state.meter1value
                    }
                    maxValue = {
                        this.props.vnfTarget
                    }
                    segments = {
                        3
                    }
                    width = {
                        400
                    }
                    height = {
                        230
                    }
                    needleColor = 'green' /
                    >
```

Answer (score 2):

Digging in the source code of react-d3-speedometer you can find this variable

```
// default config that are 'not' configurable
        var default_config = {
            ringInset: 20,

            pointerWidth: 10,
            pointerTailLength: 5,
            pointerHeadLengthPercent: 0.9,

            minAngle: -90,
            maxAngle: 90,

            labelFormat: d3Format('d'),
            labelInset: 10,

            // calculate the ReactSpeedometer 'parentNode' width/height; it might be used if fluidWidth: true
            parentWidth: self.gaugeDiv.parentNode.clientWidth,
            parentHeight: self.gaugeDiv.parentNode.clientHeight
        };
```

You need to change the following line according to your needs

```
labelFormat: d3Format('d'),
```

choosing a format from the d3 docs [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-format)